what is this dedup takes most of hard active active time and size too

This deduplication process consumes a significant portion of both active time and storage space. I've already updated Windows and done everything I can. Any suggestions?

You're looking at the wrong place
It looks like you have deduplication turned on in your file system - but that's not really the problem
KAVFSWP looks like its part of the Kaspersky Antivirus suite - and its checking those files - its mentioned here. Your system is doing a virus scan, which is a resource intensive thing, and its checking those files. In theory you could ask your AV not to scan that folder (can you?) or otherwise get your antivirus not to clobber your system, but this isn't deduplication causing issues, its a virus scan

no i have check activity no activity has been performed i also stopped kaspersky still same no chaneg

what if i stopped dedup on F: only happenng at F drive

cpu is ok only active time is too much and performance is very slow beacuse of everytime time read
